# Export Windows Registry for Services

Tags: windows, scripting, batch, vbscript

I have a process that I want to automate, I have tried doing some digging but I can't find a way to do it, as I am not a heavy scripter. Here it goes:

I want to have a script of some sort, that will search the registry and export registry keys for services for a particular application. The problem is that the application does not always have the same registry key names or services named the same across customers, since it is installed per customer. The only constant that I have found is that the services always start up in one of two folder locations, either "C:\program files (x86)\SomeApplication" or "C:\program files\SomeApplication". I also want to copy these services out to a shared location.

I need some help with tackling this please. I tried somehow using powershell, but the problem is that some of the customers I service disable powershell. I am thinking it will have to be from some sort of bat or vbs script. Please help!!!

Comment: If your PowerShell script does the job then please [edit] your question and share it; someone could help you with converting it to a batch or VBS script then…

Comment: I never made a powershell one since I was not going to be able to use it across multiple customers.